# How to pass parameters to javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget.Builder Put method

Tags: json, jax-rs

I am new to Jax-RS and Jersey 2.0. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a Resource which has the following attributes

id - String
name -String
Comments - Array of strings and i want to add a new comment to this

So I am having a REST webservice method http://host:port//rest/resourceupdate the body for this webservice must be a JSON object

Now I am trying to build a client code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import  javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

    void updateComments (String CommentToUpdate)

    {

        String url = "http://host:port/<appl>/rest/resourceupdate";
        //I am building a JSON object

        JSONObject inputObj = new JSONObject();

        //Add all the Inputs
        inputObj.put("ids", id);
        inputObj.put("name", name);

        //we need add the comments as a List

        JSONObject commentObj = new JSONObject();

        commentObj.put("comment", CommentToUpdate);


        SONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add(commentObj); 

        inputObj.put("comment", list);

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()

        WebTarget base = client.target(url);

        //But I am unable to figureout how I can send the above JSON object to the 
        //put method

        Response response = base.request().put();

    }
```

How I can send the input to put method?. Any pointers in this regard will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```java
Response response = base.request().put(Entity.json(inputObj.toJSONString()));
```